# Gatsby: WebpackError [React Intl] Could not find required `intl` object. <IntlProvider> needs to exist in the component ancestry

Tags: javascript, webpack, gatsby, react-intl, formatjs

I'm using **React Intl** for internationalisation in my **Gatsby app**. The app runs fine as expected with `npm start`, but the build fails with an error during execution of `npm run build` command.

#### Code

```js
// gatsby-browser.js

import React from "react"
import { IntlProvider } from "react-intl"

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => (
  <IntlProvider locale="en" messages={{ en: {} }}>
    {element}
  </IntlProvider>
)
```

```js
// src/pages/index.js

import React from "react"
import { useIntl } from "react-intl"

const IndexPage = () => {
  const intl = useIntl()

  return <p>index.js</p>
}

export default
```

#### Error

The `npm run build` command fails with this error.

```sh
failed Building static HTML for pages - 0.193s

 ERROR #95313 

Building static HTML failed for path "/"

See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html


  74 |     if (Err === void 0) { Err = Error; }
  75 |     if (!condition) {
> 76 |         throw new Err(message);
     | ^
  77 |     }
  78 | }
  79 |


  WebpackError: [React Intl] Could not find required `intl` object. <IntlProvider> needs to exist in the component ancestry.
  
  - utils.js:76 
    [gatsby-starter-default]/[@formatjs]/ecma402-abstract/lib/utils.js:76:1
  
  - utils.js:6 
    [gatsby-starter-default]/[react-intl]/lib/src/utils.js:6:14
  
  - useIntl.js:6 
    [gatsby-starter-default]/[react-intl]/lib/src/components/useIntl.js:6:25
  
  - index.js:5 
    gatsby-starter-default/src/pages/index.js:5:23
  
  - extends.js:3 
    [gatsby-starter-default]/[@babel]/runtime/helpers/extends.js:3:42
  
  - extends.js:2 
    [gatsby-starter-default]/[@babel]/runtime/helpers/extends.js:2:1
  
  - extends.js:13 
    [gatsby-starter-default]/[@babel]/runtime/helpers/extends.js:13:1
  
  - static-entry.js:286 
    gatsby-starter-default/.cache/static-entry.js:286:22
  
  - index.js:72 
    [gatsby-starter-default]/[@formatjs]/fast-memoize/lib/index.js:72:1
  

not finished Caching JavaScript and CSS webpack compilation - 6.623s
not finished Caching HTML renderer compilation - 0.243s
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Gatsby Documentation Says

> The APIs `wrapPageElement` and `wrapRootElement` exist in both the [browser](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-browser/) and [SSR APIs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr/). You generally should implement the same components in both `gatsby-ssr.js` and `gatsby-browser.js` so that pages generated through SSR with Node.js are the same after being [hydrated](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/glossary/#hydration) in the browser.

#### Solution

As document suggests to implement `wrapRootElement` in both `gatsby-ssr.js` and `gatsby-browser.js`, I added the code in `gatsby-ssr.js`. It worked like charm and the build didn’t fail.

For an unknown reason, the `IntlProvider` **context** was getting lost during **build time** in **SSR**.